# Counting Surnames and Ordering By most common

Tags: mysql, sql

We want to find the most common surname (LNAME) of German students (NATIONALITY). Create a view which, for every German surname, shows the surname and the number of students having that surname. The output is to be sorted in the order of most common to least common, with the secondary sort order being ascending alphabetical.

So Far I have this

```
CREATE VIEW GermanSurnames AS
SELECT LNAME, COUNT(LNAME)
FROM STUDENT
WHERE NATIONALITY = 'GERMAN'
ORDER BY LNAME DESC
```

Is this correct or how should i do this?
Thanks :)

Comment: Also missing the `group by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the group by

```
SELECT LNAME, COUNT(*) as NUMSTUDENTS
FROM STUDENT
WHERE NATIONALITY = 'GERMAN'
GROUP BY LNAME
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, LNAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Why a view? isn't

```
SELECT LNAME, COUNT(*) AS HOWMANY
  FROM STUDENT
 WHERE NATIONALITY = 'GERMAN'
 GROUP BY LNAME
 ORDER BY HOWMANY DESC;
```

sufficient?